# Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
> 'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is
> running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is
> running on a JDK, not JRE.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Bro have you solved this issue?

Comment: My project was working fine yesterday, today I got this issue out of nowhere without making any changes :(

Answer (score 0):

Download and install JDK
you can check this link for more help:
https://github.com/Jire/Charlatano/issues/854

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn
npm run android
```

Comment: update current jdk 11+

Answer (score 0):

All you had to upgrade the gradle,
go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
and change the distributionUrl to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.1-all.zip

if it doesn't work just check the current version of the gradle in the link https://gradle.org/releases/ and replace with the gradle version in distributionUrl property.